# SQL statement for combining 2 tables data without left join

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have 2 SQL tables mapped with a foreign key constraints

```
Table A

Field1 
Field2
....
```

And second one

```
Table B

Year
Value
TableAId (foreign key)
```

How can I get some output like this instead of joining 2 tables and getting Table A fields repeated in each row

```
Result

Field1
Field2
...
TableBValue1 (first value field from table B)
TableBValue2
...
```

**Some example data**

Table A

```
ID - Field 1 - Field 2 - ...

1 - "Banana" - "Cold"  - ...
2 - "Apple" - "Hot" - ...
```

Table B

```
ID - Year - Value - TableAId

1 - 2016 - 1.5 - 1
2 - 2017 - 3.2 - 1
3 - 2018 - 1.6 - 1
4 - 2016 - 1.8 - 2
5 - 2017 - 2.2 - 2
6 - 2018 - 2.6 - 2
```

Expected Result

```
ID - Field 1 - Field 2 - ... - 2016Value - 2017Value - 2018Value

1 - "Banana" - "Cold" -  ... - 1.5 - 3.2 - 1.6
2 - "Apple" - "Hot" - ... - 1.8 - 2.2 - 2.6
```

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result.

Comment: It is called aggregation. Group by the columns you want to be unique and use aggregate functions on the others like `min()`

Comment: What have you done so far and where did you get stuck!

Comment: @jarlh - I have added example data

Comment: @Lucky - I have tried Left Outer Join, but it duplicates such data like "Banana" and "Apple" in each row

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps,

```
CREATE TABLE #TableA (ID INT, F1 VARCHAR(50), F2 VARCHAR(50))
CREATE TABLE #TableB (ID INT, TableAId INT, YEAR INT, Value float)
INSERT INTO #TableA
SELECT 1,
       'Banana',
       'Cold'
UNION
SELECT 2,
       'Apple',
       'Hot'
INSERT INTO #TableB (ID, YEAR, Value, TableAId)
SELECT 1, 2016, 1.5, 1
UNION
SELECT 2, 2017, 3.2, 1
UNION
SELECT 3, 2018, 1.6, 1
UNION
SELECT 4, 2016, 1.8, 2
UNION
SELECT 5, 2017, 2.2, 2
UNION
SELECT 6, 2018, 2.6, 2
SELECT *
FROM #TableA
SELECT *
FROM #TableB GO WITH CTEResult AS
  ( SELECT TableAID,
           A.F1,
           A.F2,
           B.YEAR,
             B.Value
   FROM #TableA A
   INNER JOIN #TableB B ON A.ID = B.TableAId)
SELECT *
FROM CTEResult PIVOT (Max(Value)
                      FOR YEAR IN ([2016],[2017],[2018])) Res
```